# JavaScript charting libraries for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, charts

What JavaScript charting libraries are appropriate for mobile devices, e.g., iPhone, BlackBerry and Android?  For example, Android [currently does not support SVG](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376) and so a pure JavaScript HTML5 Canvas solution like [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is likely required.

Comment: Most of the Google Charts do not work on the default browser of Android, even on 2.2, SVG is not supported yet.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [ZingChart - JavaScript Charting Library](http://www.zingchart.com/) that renders in HTML5 Canvas, SVG, VML and/or Flash.

I'm on the team. abegin[at]zingchart.com or [www.twitter.com/zingchart](http://www.twitter.com/zingchart)

Answer (score 2):

http://katharnavas.blogspot.com/2009/11/20-best-javascript-charting-and.html

hope this will help u ...gud luck :)

Comment: Ya I am looking into that only, will let u know the feedback ..! 
Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with http://www.highcharts.com/ pre version 2 (the new version uses SVG which doesn't render on android). I know it supports the iPhone (as it says on the home page) and Android has no problems with canvas. Blackberry is the only device I'm not sure about.

Comment: It looks highcharts use SVG that does not work on Android.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure if they've changed to SVG recently but the version I have running on my machine is using canvas. We were planning to use Highcharts for the mobile platform at my company specifically because it was using canvas. I'll investigate this further. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Seems version 2 has changed to SVG.

Answer (score 1):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) should work if the mobile browser has proper HTML5 canvas support, and [Sencha Touch is planning an upcoming release with charting / drawing support](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-preview-drawing-and-charting/) ported over from the [ExtJS 4.0](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) release.

Answer (score 0):

**[ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/)** is a new chart and graph library, that brings JavaScript charts and graphs to both desktop and mobile and are very powerful and optimised (using Canvas) - it is cross device/platform compatible and has native multi-touch support.

[image]

With ZoomCharts you can create:

- timeline charts
- category charts (pie charts, facet charts)
- network graphs

and more.

Charts come with extensive API and through documentation.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Azoomcharts.com

Comment: I am one of the core developers there.

Comment: Looks very cool. But please check the [site rules about self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Isn't this propertiary ?